# SwiftUI safe update state variables from task

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

Here is my view :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let weatherLoader = WeatherLoader()
    
    @State private var temperature = ""
    @State private var pressure = ""
    @State private var humidity = ""
    @State private var tickmark = ""
    @State private var refreshable = true
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
                    GridRow {
                        Text("Температура")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(temperature) °C")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)
                    
                    GridRow {
                        Text("Давление")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(pressure) мм рт ст")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)

                    GridRow {
                        Text("Влажность")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(humidity) %")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)

                    GridRow {
                        Text("Дата обновления")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(tickmark)")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)
                }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8)
                
                Button("Обновить") {
                    refreshable = false
                    print("handler : \(Thread.current)")
                    Task.detached {
                        print("task : \(Thread.current)")
                        let result = await weatherLoader.loadWeather()
                        await MainActor.run {
                            print("main actor: \(Thread.current)")
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let item):
                                temperature = item.temperature
                                pressure = item.pressure
                                humidity = item.humidity
                                tickmark = item.date
                            case .failure:
                                temperature = ""
                                pressure = ""
                                humidity = ""
                                tickmark = ""
                            }
                            
                            refreshable = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                .disabled(!refreshable)
                .padding()
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .frame(width: 320, height: 240)
    }
}
```

The question is - what is the right way to update `@State` variables from async context? I see that there is no failure if I get rid of `MainActor.run` but when dealing with `UIKit` we must call this update from main thread. Does it differ here? I also learned that Task inherits `MainActor` context, so I put `Task.detached` to make sure that it's another thread than main. Could anyone make it clear for me?

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question at hand, but we general avoid the `Result` pattern nowadays. I might advise refactoring the `Result`-based `func loadWeather() async -> Result<WeatherReport, Error> {…}` to be a throwing function, e.g., `func loadWeather() async throws -> WeatherReport {…}`.

Comment: Thanks for your note, Rob - I'll refactor it according to your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a task using

```
Task { @MainActor in
    //
}
```

then the code within the Task itself will run on the main queue, but any async calls *it* makes can run on any queue.

Adding an implementation of `WeatherLoader` as follows:

```
class WeatherLoader {
    
    func loadWeather() async throws -> Item {
        print("load : \(Thread.current)")
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        return Item()
    }
}
```

and then calling like:

```
print("handler : \(Thread.current)")
Task { @MainActor in
    print("task : \(Thread.current)")
    do {
        let item = try await weatherLoader.loadWeather()
        print("result : \(Thread.current)")
        temperature = item.temperature
        pressure = item.pressure
        humidity = item.humidity
        tickmark = item.date
    } catch {
        temperature = ""
        pressure = ""
        humidity = ""
        tickmark = ""
    }
        
    refreshable = true
}
```

you'll see something like

```
handler : <_NSMainThread: 0x6000000f02c0>{number = 1, name = main}
task : <_NSMainThread: 0x6000000f02c0>{number = 1, name = main}
load : <NSThread: 0x6000000a1e00>{number = 6, name = (null)}
result : <_NSMainThread: 0x6000000f02c0>{number = 1, name = main}
```

As you can see, `handler` and `task` run on the main queue, `load` runs on some other, and then `result` is back on the main queue.
As the code within the Task itself is guaranteed to run on the main queue, it's safe to update State variables from there.

As you mention above, `@MainActor in` isn't actually required in this case, `Task(priority:operation:)` inherits the priority and actor context of the caller.

However, running a task using

```
Task.detached(priority: .background) {
    //
}
```

gives an output like:

```
handler : <_NSMainThread: 0x600003a28780>{number = 1, name = main}
task : <NSThread: 0x600003a6fe80>{number = 8, name = (null)}
load : <NSThread: 0x600003a6fe80>{number = 8, name = (null)}
result : <NSThread: 0x600003a7d100>{number = 6, name = (null)}
```

`handler` runs on the main queue,then `task` and `load` run on some other, and then interestingly `result` is on an entirely different one again after `loadWeather()` returns.

After all that, in answer your question *"why do not I see a crash if I use .detach for Task and get rid of MainActor.run in my code?"*, presumably this is because your `ContentView` is a value type, and therefore thread safe. If you move your `@State` properties to `@Published` in `WeatherLoader`, then you will get background thread warnings.

Comment: He's in SwiftUI so shouldn't use `Task` at all, should be using `.task`

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, we use async/await from `.task`, not from `Button`. We can also update `@State` vars fine inside it. Try this instead:

```
Button("Обновить") {
    refresh = true
}
.task(id: refresh) {
    if !refresh {
        return 
    }
    let result = await weatherLoader.loadWeather()

    // it pauses computation here and will return after the async loading has finished. It could return on any thread but any calls to update state below will be done safely.

    switch result {
         case .success(let item):
         temperature = item.temperature
         pressure = item.pressure
         humidity = item.humidity
         tickmark = item.date
     case .failure:
         temperature = ""
         pressure = ""
         humidity = ""
         tickmark = ""
     }
     refresh = false
}
```

`.task` will run when the value of `refresh` changes and is cancelled if the view disappears. If you want to cancel the task and restart it every button press you could change `refresh` from a bool to a `refreshCounter` and increment it on the button press.

Hopefully `weatherLoader` is a struct because `View` structs shouldn't init objects, it's a memory leak.

Comment: The OP asked how to initiate an asynchronous process on a button tap. Or more generally, how one initiates some asynchronous task based upon some interaction in the UI. It is weird to post an answer that says “do not use a button”. Lol. Sure, offer the `.task {…}` as an alternative, but it's definitely not the answer to the OPs question. (And it certainly doesn't warrant posting comments under all the other answers that do address the OP’s original question.)

Comment: `.task` is an async context. Every line that has await is asynchronous. Structured concurrency it's called. But thanks, I added a comment for those who maybe are unfamiliar with how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I … learned that `Task` inherits `MainActor` context, so I put `Task.detached` to make sure that it’s another thread than `main`.

The end goal, to make sure you are updating your properties on the main actor (and thus the main thread) is correct. These must be updated from the main actor.

That having been said, you do not need to (nor do you want to) use a detached task. When the main actor hits an `await`, that particular path of execution is suspended, and the main actor is free to carry on doing other things until the `loadWeather` is done. The `await` doesn’t block the current thread, but rather frees it to go do other things. This eliminates all of the GCD silliness of “let me dispatch this to some background queue, and when that’s done, dispatch the update back to the main queue.”

So, consider:

```swift
Button("Обновить") {
    refreshable = false
    Task.detached {
        let result = await weatherLoader.loadWeather()
        await MainActor.run {
            switch result {
            case .success(let item):
                temperature = item.temperature
                …
            case .failure:
                temperature = ""
                …
            }
            
            refreshable = true
        }
    }
}
```

This should be simplified to:

```swift
Button("Обновить") {
    refreshable = false
    Task {
        let result = await weatherLoader.loadWeather()
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let item):
            temperature = item.temperature
            …
        case .failure:
            temperature = ""
            …
        }
        
        refreshable = true
    }
}
```

The only time you need to use a detached task is when you have some slow *synchronous* task that you need to get off the current actor.

But that’s not what is going on here. You have an asynchronous `loadWeather` API, which you `await`. So you can use `Task {…}`, which runs the task on the current actor (i.e., the main actor).

---

So, you ask:

> The question is - what is the right way to update `@State` variables from `async` context?

The right solution is to mark these properties as `@MainActor`, and then the compiler will warn you if you ever try to update them from the wrong context.

Or, rather than marking the individual properties as `@MainActor`, I personally pull all of this logic out of the view, and put it on a view model which is isolated to the main actor. E.g.:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var temperature = ""
    @Published var pressure = ""
    @Published var humidity = ""
    @Published var tickmark = ""
    @Published var refreshable = true

    private let weatherLoader = WeatherLoader()

    func update() async {
        refreshable = false

        let result = await weatherLoader.loadWeather()

        switch result {
        case .success(let item):
            temperature = item.temperature
            pressure = item.pressure
            humidity = item.humidity
            tickmark = item.date
        case .failure:
            temperature = ""
            pressure = ""
            humidity = ""
            tickmark = ""
        }

        refreshable = true
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { metrics in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
                    GridRow {
                        Text("Температура")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(viewModel.temperature) °C")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)

                    GridRow {
                        Text("Давление")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(viewModel.pressure) мм рт ст")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)

                    GridRow {
                        Text("Влажность")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(viewModel.humidity) %")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)

                    GridRow {
                        Text("Дата обновления")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                        Text("\(viewModel.tickmark)")
                            .frame(width: metrics.size.width/2)
                    }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8*0.25)
                }.frame(height: metrics.size.height*0.8)

                Button("Обновить") {
                    Task { await viewModel.update() }
                }
                .disabled(!viewModel.refreshable)
                .padding()
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Frankly, the integration with some third-party web service does not belong in the view anyway.

You then ask:

> I see that there is no failure if I get rid of `MainActor.run` but when dealing with UIKit we must call this update from main thread. Does it differ here?

No, it is the same here. It must update on the main thread. If you use the main actor, that will ensure you use the main thread. You do not need `MainActor.run`. (And nine times out of ten, the use of `MainActor.run` is a mistake, and is offer better achieved by getting properties and methods on the correct actor in the first place.)

Comment: The point of async/await and `.task` is to remove the need for `@StateObject`

Comment: That’s simply not true. Besides, the `@StateObject` is merely a means to an end. Namely, a view model is to abstract business logic (e.g., fetching of details from some third party service) from the view logic. The `@StateObject` is merely the mechanism to associate a view model with a view.

Comment: No `@StateObject` is the mechanism for using a reference type as `@State`. View struct is a view model.

Comment: Lol. No, a `View` is a “view” not a “view model”. Looks at all that geometry reader and grid code. Do you really want to entangle that with your business logic?!? That's not how most of us interpret MVVM in SwiftUI. We like to abstract view specific logic away from business logic. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introducing-mvvm-into-your-swiftui-project.

Comment: @Rob, you said : "This eliminates all of the GCD silliness of “let me dispatch this to some background queue, and when that’s done, dispatch the update back to the main queue.” And is it possible to select or maybe advice to what thread a task is gonna be dispatched ?

Comment: If you really care about the Swift concurrency threading model, refer to WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/). It is an interesting watch. But, FWIW, with Swift concurrency, we simply don’t worry about on which thread something runs, but we only specify what methods and properties need the main actor, and let Swift concurrency take care of it from there. As an aside, looking at `Thread.current` from an async context can be misleading (and is going to be prohibited entirely in a future compiler release).